# Check if a string contains some specific values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to check if a string is a url that contains http, https,www. For this i created this function:

```js
const test = (str) => {
  const res = new RegExp(/(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)/ig);

  return res.test(str);
};

console.log(test('https://www.codepen.io'), 'test');
console.log(test('www.codepen.io'), 'test');
console.log(test('http://www.codepen.io'), 'test');
```

I expect to get `true` for all tests, but the second one give `false`. What could be the issue?

Comment: The `https://` part is not optional in your regex.

Comment: Why do you use the `RegExp` constructor? There's nothing variable in the expression that would require the use of the constructor.

Comment: Note that `new RegExp()` expects a **string** parameter, this way you create a Regexp using `//` and put that into the constructor, which then converts it to string before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be:

```js
const res = new RegExp("^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)", "ig");
```

Comment: but in this way, i will require only https? Or i am wrong? `https?` does not mean that we set just for htttps?

Comment: Note that `new RegExp()` expects a **string** parameter (mistake by question asker, but you kept it), this way you create a Regexp using // and put that into the constructor, which then converts it to string before using it.

Comment: Thanks Peter. And `https?` the `?` only refers to last character, so it’s `http` or `https`.

Comment: @Cyrille Pontvieux, also if i test `console.log(test('hps://www.codepen.io'), 'test');`, i get `true`, but it should be false, because i expect only http or https. How to solve that?

Comment: I made an edit, you should add the caret character `^` which means *starts with*

Comment: @CyrillePontvieux, also i try to set new RegExp("^(https?:\/\/)?(www\{3}.)", "ig"), to get only links that contains only 3 `www`, if it contains 4 of `wwww` it should be rejcted, but it does not work. Do you know a solution? Basically in this case `console.log(test('http://wwww.codepen.io'), 'test');` i should get false.

Comment: just use `www` or `w{3}` but not `www{3}` as it would mean two w followed by three w.

Comment: As the parameter of the constructor is a string, the actual regular expression is: `/^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)/ig` - no literal `.` after `www`

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```js
const test = (str) => str.includes('www.') || (/^((https|http|ftp):\/\/)/i).test(str);

console.log(test('https://www.codepen.io'), 'test');
console.log(test('www.codepen.io'), 'test');
console.log(test('http://www.codepen.io'), 'test');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```